# why destructuring is undefined when I don't use a semicolon at end line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

I tried spread in javascript (node and chrome).

thanks to @jonrsharpe, @Quentin show me  [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) explains that semicolon is necessary and that explain why is necessary use a semicolon.

```
let c, d
[ c, ] = [7, 8]; // <-- semicolon is necessary 
[ , d ] = [7, 8] // Otherwise, here: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

```
let c, d
[ , d ] = [7, 8]; // <-- semicolon is necessary 
[ c, ] = [7, 8] // Otherwise, here: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
```

Just for curious, I keep tried testing without semicolon and discover this behavior:

```
let c, d
[ c, ] = [3, 4]
[ c, d ] = [5, 6]
console.log(c) //<-- 5
console.log(d) //<-- undefined
```

what explains 'd' keeps "undefined"? 
I hoped at least an error o d with some value.

Comment: Apparently, it is necessary use semicolon in line before use destructuring to avoid unexpected behaviour.  Otherwise, javascript consider variables or values as position in array.